# Cakephp routes.php stops working after I changed the content in the default .htaccess file. How to update .htaccess to resume basic url routing

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite, cpanel

e.g. my-domian/yyy yyy can't be recognized by my routes.php

I accidentally delete the content in my .htaccess file.

The routes.php file (router file) no longer route my site properly.

routes.php:

```
Router::scope('/', function ($routes) {
//this one works
$routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home']);
//these two routes no longer work
$routes->connect('/survey', ['controller' => 'Surveys', 'action' => 'get']);
$routes->connect('/scenario', ['controller' => 'Scenarios', 'action' => 'get']); });
```

my-domain/ works.

my-domain/survey?xx=3  no longer works.

404 error I got for my-domain/survey?xx=3 :

```
File does not exist: /home/nexusuto/public_html/survey
```

my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule ^(.*/)?\.svn/ - [F,L]
        ErrorDocument 403 "Access Forbidden"
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.*
        RewriteRule .* – [F,L]
</IfModule>
```

Please help me... I have been stuck for a long time :(((( I just want to resume the basic use of .htaccess file i.e. I can route my-domain/survey to my survey controller..

Comment: Perhaps you should review the official documentation on [CakePHP URL Rewriting](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html).

Comment: If you don't know how to write .htaccess rules, then simple copy one from fresh downloaded cakephp folder.

Comment: https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/master/.htaccess

Comment: @Salines please make that an answer. Be sure to mention to copy the `.htaccess` files for the version in use - they change (slightly) with new major versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have not modified the file routes.php just create .htaccess again

Try with this .htaccess structures:

ROOT .HTACCESS

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase      /
   RewriteRule      ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule     (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

app/ .HTACCESS

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase     /app/
    RewriteRule     ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

app/webroot/ .HTACCESS

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase     /app/webroot
    RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule     ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

But if you modify routes file maybe you should try this:

```
$routes->connect('/survey/*', ['controller' => 'Surveys', 'action' => 'get']);
```

> The URL is a normal slash delimited string, but can also contain a
>   wildcard (*) or Route Elements. Using a wildcard tells the router that
>   you are willing to accept any additional arguments supplied. Routes
>   without a * only match the exact template pattern supplied.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#connecting-routes

Answer (score 1):

If you do not know how to write a .htaccess rules, then simply downloading the same [version of CakePHP](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/tags) and replace .htaccess in your web application.